# PythonAnywhere "Cannot import name dateparse"

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am following instructions from [this site](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html).

I am doing this in PythonAnywhere.

When I run this code:

```
>>> from provider.oauth2.models import Client
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> c = Client(user=u, name="mysite client", client_type=1,url="http://ianalexandr.com")
>>> c.save()
>>> c.client_id
'd63f53a7a6cceba04db5'
>>> c.client_secret
'afe899288b9ac4127d57f2f12ac5a49d839364dc'
```

I get this error:

```
line 5, in <module>
from django.utils import dateparse
ImportError: cannot import name dateparse
```

I am not sure if PythonAnywhere does have dateparse in its library.
and if not, then how can i include dateparse?

Comment: I would say that the Django package that PythonAnywhere provides is imcomplete (or perhaps very, very old). Could you check your Django version? `>>> import django; django.get_version()`.

Comment: Also, could you indicate whether it is indeed after that last line (`c.client_secret`) that you get the error, or perhaps a line before that?

Comment: @Evert im sure that im getting error from the header

Comment: @Evert using python2.7 i did get the version of django which is: 1.3.7

Comment: We have to pin the version of Django to avoid breaking existing sites. We're working on making things more upgradeable, but in the meantime, you can use a virtualenv to use a specific version of Django. There are instructions for that in the Help for PythonAnywhere.

Comment: "im getting error from the header". I don't know what you mean by that. I don't see a header in the code here.

Comment: @Evert Im referring to the imports :P im a django noobie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Django is too old. `utils.dateparse` was introduced in [1.4](https://github.com/django/django/tree/1.4.15/django/utils).
Version 1.3 is almost ancient, and not [supported anymore](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/#supported-versions) by the Django developers (that is, there will be no security updates).
Consider upgrading to a more recent version if you can. Upgrading to 1.4 (with long term support) will break the least, or upgrade to 1.7 which is the most recent version, but may break most old code.

**Edit**

I just saw Glenn's note; that explains how you can work around this problem, since the current 1.3 version appears to be pretty much fixed.

Comment: thank you so much. I've realised it as well when you asked me to do some version check.